# Domain to main domain 301 redirection

Tags: redirect

I would like to setup a rule in Apache so that each time that a visitor gets redirected to my official domain (www.mydomaincom) whenever he's heading to mydomain.com. Here's what I have set in Apache but it does not work:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot c:/websites/mydomain.com/www/httpdocs
    CustomLog "c:/websites/mydomain.com/www/logs/access.log" lscommon
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias *.mydomain.com
    RewriteEngine On
    <Directory />
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mydomain.com$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1):

I do the exact same thing, but in reverse:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=Permanent]
```

Note: the `[R=Permanent]` flag uses a `301 Moved Permanently` redirect.

So for you, that would be:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=Permanent]
```

Secondly, take it out of the `<Directory>` tag.